# Wrong review question?

Tags: discussion, review-audits, triage, spam

I do not see how this review question could be spam or offensive: https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/20462542. Could someone explain it?

Comment: What is the question? (<10k)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I handled the flags and should have then cleared the flags to prevent the post being used as a review audit, as it's not obviously to most users that it's spam.

I will lift your review ban.

Within the post it referenced a [frequently spammed site](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&title=&body=forskolin&username=&why=&site=&post_type=&feedback=&autoflagged=&reason=&user_rep_direction=%3E%3D&user_reputation=0&commit=Search) on the network. It has been spammed 1947 times that we know of, through charcoal.

[image]

They also posted the question twice:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51384914/using-selectors-in-nightmare-js

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51386734/clicking-menu-options-in-nightmare-js

As we've had spammers use code to attempt to slip in their promotions I chose to delete it and destroy the account.

Now it's possible the user was genuine, in which case that was bad luck to choose that url for their test code.

I've asked for a feature request on Meta Stack Exchange to address this isse:

[Can we have a mod tool to prevent posts from being selected for review audits, without invalidating flags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/313455/can-we-have-a-mod-tool-to-prevent-posts-from-being-selected-for-review-audits-w)

Comment: Small nitpick. The keyword *forskolin* has been spammed 1950 times, the specific website in question `activeforskolinplan.com` has not seen any occurences on the network outside of that user's 2 questions: https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&title=&body=activeforskolinplan&username=&why=&site=&post_type=&feedback=&autoflagged=&reason=&user_rep_direction=%3E%3D&user_reputation=0&commit=Search

Comment: @Magisch that's really a red herring. It's the keyword that's banned. A link to the actual site is no improvement. Your comment will mislead people who don't follow the process.

Comment: Would it make sense to have a list somewhere, maybe accessible from review queues to see the list of frequented spam?

Comment: @WhatsThePoint there's github repos and a site you can search on. I'll find some links. The issue is, the mods need a tool to prevent posts from going into review audits, but still being able to mark them as spam.

Comment: @YvetteColomb yes that's true as preventing audits like this will be a good start, but if the information of known spammers is external and not easily accessible to users, then spam like this could creep through and not get noticed for a while (yes I know some of the bots can pick it up but if the users seeing what the bots spit out aren't to know then more cases like this can happen)

Comment: @Magisch Most feedbacks are false positives, which assumed reviewers are agree both posts are in good standing. This issue sounds similar to [this case](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/post/128367) which declared URL string in code had redacted immediately.

Comment: "Forskolin" is the name of a chemical which has traditionally been thought to aid weight loss. This particular URL does *not* look like the [predominant pharma spammer's](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/298538/what-do-we-know-about-the-stack-exchange-pharma-spammer) (different route arrangement, non-typical whois registration).

Answer (score 6):

As rene already mentioned in [his comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/371834/wrong-review-question#comment615905_371834), the post was deleted by a moderator as spam.

It came up on SmokeDetector (a community run spam detection bot) before that, because the website used in the code block of the question has a pattern in its name that is *really* frequently used in spam. The review in Smoke Detector at the time came up unconclusive, with it being marked as false positive by at least one user. A moderator must have disagreed.

Audits are chosen automatically, the "known bad spam" type of audit you got is chosen randomly from destroyed spam posts. So you got unlucky to get a borderline case like this.

In particular, that keyword has been used in at least 1947 [confirmed spam posts](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&title=&body=forskolin&username=&why=&site=&post_type=&feedback=&autoflagged=&reason=&user_rep_direction=%3E%3D&user_reputation=0&commit=Search) across the network.

Comment: "Unlucky" is sort of built in to the audit mechanism. Some people are known to repeat the mantra "audits are broken".